# Where are the Intel XDK build logs?

Tags: intel-xdk

When I build XDK for iOS, I get the message 'An error occurred while building the application. Verify your build assets are correct and try again':

[image: failed build iOS]

I have searched online and checked the build assets, but can't find anything wrong, so I am stuck.

Is there any way that I can see the log for the build to tell what went wrong? I can't seem to find a link to the logs anywhere, either in the XDK application or the online AppCenter.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I received a reply on the [Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/558489#comment-1825372) to use the Cordova iOS build where there is a link to the build logs.

I was swapping between Cordova and legacy ad-hoc to try to get things working and maybe I got mixed up somewhere along the way. Anyway, I changed two things and it is building OK now with Cordova iOS: -

- I found an android setting in the iOS config file that I removed.
- I changed the app name, because I read that if it started with the project name that could cause issues.

Comment: Hmm, I still wonder where to find the Android Build logs. I still get a similar message like you had, but without any link to a logfile. Does anybody know?